# Perfect set without rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Sorry if this problem is repeated.

Is there a nonempty perfect set in $\mathbb{R}^1$ which contains no rational number?

**Proof sketch:**
This set must be uncountable because *any nonempty perfect set in $\mathbb{R}^k$ is uncountable.*

We know that Cantor set (C) is perfect set on a line. If we take $E=C+\sqrt{2}=\{x+\sqrt{2}: x\in C\}$. Will this set be an answer to above problem?

Comment: See example 5 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&pg=PA89&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064/perfect-set-without-rationals?rq=1) also.

Comment: I read this. I concluded that my example is also satisfies. Am I true?

Comment: Some translate would work See [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/158378/a-translation-of-the-cantor-set-contained-in-the-irrationals). I'm not sure if $\sqrt 2$ does it...

Comment: I understood you! Because Cantor set contains irrational numbers. Quite possible that $x+r\in \mathbb{Q}$ where $x\in C$ and $r\in \mathbb{Q}^c$. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The irrationals are homeomorphic to the space $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ with the product topology; you’ll find two proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352547/baire-space-homeomorphic-to-irrationals). The Cantor set is well-known to be homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ with the product topology, where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology. Thus, if $h:\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}\to\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ is a homeomorphism, $h\left[\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}\right]$ is a Cantor set contained in the irrationals.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't look at the links posted in the comments. I may repeat an argument there in the below.

Suppose $E$ is the set of all $x\in [0,1]$ such that $x$ has a decimal expansion of the form

$$\tag  1  .\text {_} 0 \text {_ _} 0 \text {_ _ _}  0 \text {_ _ _ _} 0 \dots ,$$

where the entries in the blanks _ are either $1$ or $2.$ Such expansions are unique; we don't run into the "string of $9$'s" business. Therefore $E$ has the same cardinality as the set of binary sequences, hence is uncountable.

Because the expansions in $(1)$ are nonrepeating, $E$ contains no rational. If a sequence in $E$ converges, the corresponding decimal expansions converge in each slot (we don't run into the $.4999\bar 9 = .5000\bar 0$ problem). Hence $E$ is closed.

Finally $E$ is perfect: Let $x\in E.$ Suppose $x$ has infinitely many $1$'s in its expansion, say in the slots $n_1,n_2, \dots.$ Then $x+1/10^{n_k} \to x,$ and each $x+1/10^{n_k} \in E.$ If $x$ had $2$'s in the slots $n_1,n_2, \dots,$ we would instead look at $x-1/10^{n_k} \to x.$ So $E$ is perfect as desired.