# A perfect set without any rationals - Perfect minus Rationals?

Tags: real-analysis

This has already been asked several times and well answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358496/perfect-set-without-rational-numbers) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064/perfect-set-without-rationals) so I am asking if my approach is correct or not. My question is as follows

> Suppose $E$ is a set in $[0, 1]$ whose decimal expansion consists only of $\{4, 7\}$. It can be shown that $E$ is perfect set. Is $E \setminus \Bbb Q$ perfect?

I cannot find any isolated point but I am confused about $E\setminus \Bbb Q$ being closed.

Comment: Let $(X,d)$ be a  complete  metric space. (1). If $X$ is non-empty and has no isolated points then $X$ has a subspace $D$  which is homeomorphic to the Cantor set. So $D$ is a perfect set. (2). If $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ then the subspace topology on $Y$ can be generated by a complete metric $e$ on $Y$ iff $Y$ is a $G_{\delta}$  subset  of $X.$.... By (2), $\Bbb R$ \ $\Bbb Q$ is completely metrizable. So by (1), $\Bbb R$ \ $\Bbb Q$ has a perfect subset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, $E\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is **not** perfect. For example, consider the sequence:

- $0.47447444744447444447...$
- $0.447447444744447444447...$
- $0.4447447444744447444447...$
- $0.44447447444744447444447...$
- $0.444447447444744447444447...$
- $0.4444447447444744447444447...$
- ...

Each number in the sequence is in $E\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, but the limit of the sequence is $0.44444....$ which is rational. So $E\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed.

Comment: I see ... thank you :)