# On compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

Basically, I know how to prove that every compact subspace of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the subspace topology has empty interior, but is the same true for irrationals? It's Just some thought I had and couldn't find a proof or an example for this statement. Here looking for some tips

Comment: Please sketch your proof of the fact that every compact subset of $\mathbb Q$ has empty interior, so we can see why it doesn't work for the irrationals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $C$ be a compact subset of $\Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$ and assume that $C$ has a non-empty interior under the subspace topology on $\Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$. So there are real numbers $a < b$ such that $(\Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}) \cap (a, b) \subseteq C$. We can pick $x \in \Bbb{Q} \cap (a, b)$ and then, for each $n = 1, 2, \ldots$, we can pick $x_n \in C \cap (a, b)$ such that $|x - x_n| < \frac{1}{n}$. Then $x_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$, but $x_n$ is a sequence of points in the compact metric space $C$, so, if it has a limit point, that limit point lies in $C$, but $x \in \Bbb{Q}$ and so cannot lie in $C$. This contradicts our assumption that $C$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$ with a non-empty interior: no such $C$ exists.

The above argument generalises easily to show that if $X$ is any dense subset of $\Bbb{R}$ whose complement is dense, then a compact subset of $X$ has an empty interior. I would be a little surprised if the proof you know for $X = \Bbb{Q}$ exploited some special properties of the rationals and hence didn't generalise.

Comment: And the same goes for any Hausdorff space in place of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

Rob Arthan's answer is a very good answer. I thought I'd share another (fun) way to approach this using a (rather bizarre) quirk about the space of irrational numbers.

> **Theorem.** Equip $\mathbb N$ with the discrete topology. Then, with the product topology, the space $\prod_{j\in\mathbb N} \mathbb N$ of sequences of natural numbers is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ with the usual subspace topology.

For details about this, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/769813 .

The product topology on $\prod_{j\in\mathbb N} \mathbb N$ is the topology generated by the basis
$$\mathfrak B =\left\{\, \prod_{j\in\mathbb N} U_j : U_j \subseteq \mathbb N \text{, and } U_j = \mathbb N \text{ for all but finitely many }j \,\right\}.$$

We have the following lemma:

> **Lemma.** Let $K \subseteq \prod_{j\in\mathbb N} \mathbb N$ be compact. Then $K$ is closed, and $K \subseteq \prod_{j\in\mathbb N} F_j$ for some collection $\{F_j\}_{j\in\mathbb N}$ of finite subsets of $\mathbb N$.

*Proof.* To see that $K$ is closed only requires us to notice that $K$ is compact in a Hausdorff space. Now for each $i \in \mathbb N$, define the projection $\pi_i \colon \prod_{j\in\mathbb N} \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ of the $i$-th coordinate by $\pi((x_1,x_2,\dots)) = x_i$. Note that these $\pi_i$'s are continuous. Suppose the 2nd part of the conclusion of the lemma doesn't hold for some compact $K \subseteq \prod_{j\in\mathbb N} \mathbb N$. Then there exists some $i\in\mathbb N$ such that $\pi_i(K)$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb N$. However $\pi_i(K)$ is then not compact (because we are equipping $\mathbb N$ with the discrete topology), contradicting the fact that the continuous image of any compact set must necessarily be compact. $\square$

*Remark.* The converse to this lemma also holds, but is not necessary for this answer.

Now observe that if $\{F_j\}_{j\in\mathbb N}$ is a collection of finite subsets of $\mathbb N$, then the product $\prod_{j\in\mathbb N} F_j$ must have empty interior. This is because any open set in the basis $\mathfrak B$ cannot be a subset of $\prod_{j\in\mathbb N} F_j$, due to the requirement of elements of $\mathfrak B$ needing to have infinitely many copies of $\mathbb N$ in the product.

Therefore for any compact $K \subseteq \prod_{j\in\mathbb N} \mathbb N$, the observation above together with the lemma imply that $K$ must be nowhere dense.

Comment: +1: cute and very instructive about $\Bbb{R}\setminus\Bbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $E$ is a Hausdorff space, and if $S$ is a dense subspace of $E$ with empty interior, then every compact subset of $S$ has empty interior relative to $S$.

**Proof.** Let $K$ be a compact subset of $S$. Then $K$ is closed in $E$, since $E$ is Hausdorff. Since $\operatorname{int}_S(K)$ is open in $S$, there is an open subset $U$ of $E$ such that $\operatorname{int}_S(K)=U\cap S$. Since $U$ is open and $S$ is dense in $E$, we have $U\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_E(U\cap S)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_E(K)=K\subseteq S$. Since $S$ has empty interior in $E$, we must have $U=\varnothing$, so $\operatorname{int}_S(K)=U\cap S=\varnothing$.

To see why Hausdorff (or at least some separation axiom) is needed, let $E=\{0,1\}$ with the trivial topology, and let $S=K=\{0\}$.